# I want to switch button image on click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, button

I want to change the image of button on click. click once 1 image should be set on he button and when again clicked the 2nd image should be there and these images should switch on click.

Comment: ok do it..what is the question?

Comment: Sounds like a plan, let us know how it turns out.

Comment: How to do this :( . 
I placed one image on the button. 
dont know how to switch image.

Comment: I don't understand the question the way that the replies do.

smorgan seems to be asking for a toggle and not a down state.

Answer (score 9):

Add a button to your view, remove the title and set the type to toggle(in the attributes tab of the inspector). Here also set the image and alternate image of your button like this:

[attributes inspector http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/2310/bildschirmfoto20090928u.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/2310/bildschirmfoto20090928u.png)

That should do it.

If you want to use a custom image you will have to do it programatically like this:

```
NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" 
                              ofType:@"png"];
NSURL* url      = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSImage *image  = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];

[myButton setImage: image];
```

and respectively for the alternate image:

```
[myButton setAlternateImage: image2];
```

Comment: “If you want to use a custom image you will have to do it programatically …” Not necessarily. `imageNamed:` finds images in loaded bundles as well, so as long as the image is in such a bundle (such as the main bundle), you can still put its name in one of those fields in IB and it'll work just fine.